# dropwizard using hibernateSpetial

Tags: java

i m new in hibernate spatial and i would trying to retrieve geometry data from postgresql databse. i use following jar:

```
postgis-jdbc 1.5.3.jar,jts.jar 1.12
```

the database column is: gpslocation geometry(Point,4326)

And i m retrieving this column using following query,but it give me an error for
Can't convert String object.,so how can i fix this error can any one suggest me?

```
Session session=currentSession();

    SQLQuery q =  session
            .createSQLQuery(
                    "select ST_AsText('POINT',4326) as location");
    q.addScalar("location", StringType.INSTANCE); 
    String result = (String) q.list().get(4);

    session.close();
    session.getTransaction().commit();

    return result;
```